# How to check status of process approvement app to Google Apps Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We developed app for Google Apps Marketplace and integrate it with required API. 
And I filled out the Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request to week ago and still my apps isn't in Google Apps Marketplace but it is in Chrome Web Store.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish an app before the review. You should see it available from the Admin Console. The review is post-publishing and the review team will contact you if something is wrong.

Are you sure you published it in the CWS developer dashboard?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. My app is published in Chrome Web Store - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cooperation534/fhoapaadglnjnkpcheondjmokpclpeek?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: There is no way to know whether the app is approved or not and the app doesn't appear in any search results. The developer is in the dark.